# What are these marks with the numbers designating the Jewish years on this calendar?

Tags: number, hebrew, calendar

I can see that the Hebrew is Elul 775 to Tishrei 776. What are those marks prior to the Hay and the Vav?

[image: calendar]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are a [Gershayim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershayim), a Hebrew diacritic used in a number of ways, but generally to indicate that a certain set of letters does not spell a word in the ordinary sense. In this case, it is used to indicate that the letters are to be taken as numerals.

Comment: Why are there two? Why are they before the last letter in each case, but only one after the Bet in Adar Bet? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AdamHrankowski For single letter instances, a [Geresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geresh#Denoting_a_numeral) is generally used instead with generally the same effect.

Comment: @AdamHrankowski As you noted in your question, the years listed are 775 and 776. If you wanted to say 5776 (the current year), many write ה'תשע"ו, with the ה' representing 5000 years. (Sometimes people also write תשע"ו לפ"ק\תשע"ו לפרק קטן)

Comment: DoubleAA, re your comment: It's not so much single- versus multiple-letter (though that's true for numbers) as truncation versus other abbreviation. Thus, מיי׳ and וכו׳. cc @AdamHrankowski

Comment: @AdamHrankowski, I would encourage you to [ask additional questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Shokhet: the abbreviation "Lamed Feh Kuf" stands for "LiFrat Katan," or "according to the smaller number, ie. "not including the large number," the number for thousands. There is a matching abbreviation for use with a number which includes the letter for thousands, that is, "Lamed Feh Gimel," which stands for "LiFrat Gadol."